# Using filen.io sync client, sync only some directorieswithout giving credentials for others

Tags: sync, online-storage

I'm using filen.io dropbox-like service, which has a nice lifetime plan and zero-knowledge encryption.

I'd like to sync some "public" directories on a weakly secured computer using the sync client, just like "selective sync" would (in short, "selective sync" means listing only some cloud directories to keep in sync, with local "mount points").

The problem is that selective sync needs to be fully connected to my account, and accessing my other "private" data from that computer would not require additional credentials. Is there a simple way to have a restricted workspace (bunch of directories) that I can sync with a dedicated password, without giving access to my account?

Comment: Show the most relevant findings from https://filen.io/support and explain why they don't meet your needs. Also add more details like the name and version of your operative system and what you have tried like using two accounts, sending a support request  to the developers , etc.